# Prediction always the same while using Sci-kit Learn SVM

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataset where I'm trying to predict what kind of DNA a data entry is from the DNA makeup. For example, the string `ATTAG...ACGAT` might translate to `EI`. The possible outputs are either `EI`, `IE`, or `N`. The dataset can be investigated further [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Molecular+Biology+%28Splice-junction+Gene+Sequences%29). I tried switching out kernels from `linear` to `rbf` but the results are the same. The SVM classifier seems to output `N` everytime. Any ideas why? I'm a beginner to Sci-kit Learn.

```
import pandas as pd
# 3190 total
training_data = pd.read_csv('new_training.csv')
test_data = pd.read_csv('new_test.csv')
frames = [training_data, test_data]
data = pd.concat(frames)
x = data.iloc[:, 0:59]
y = data.iloc[:, 60]

x = pd.get_dummies(x)
train_x = x.iloc[0:3000, :]
train_y = y.iloc[0:3000]
test_x = x.iloc[3000:3190, :]
test_y = y.iloc[3000:3190]

from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import preprocessing

clf = svm.SVC(kernel="rbf")
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(y)

print(label_encoder.transform(train_y))
clf.fit(train_x, label_encoder.transform(train_y))

for u in train_y.unique():
    print(u)

predictions = clf.predict(test_x)

correct = 0
total = len(predictions)
for i in range(total):
    prediction = label_encoder.inverse_transform(predictions[i])
    print('predicted %s and actual %s' % (prediction, test_y[i]))
    print(len(prediction))
    if prediction == test_y[i]:
        correct += 1

print('correct %d out of %d' % (correct, total))
```

First I import the training and test data, combine it and split it into as either x (inputs) or y (output label). Then I convert x into the dummy variable version from the original 60 columns to like 300~ columns since each DNA spot can be `A`, `T`, `G`, `C` and sometimes `N`. Basically have either a 0 or 1 for all the possible inputs for each input. (Is there a better way to do this? Sci-kit learn doesn't support categorical encoding and I tried best I could from [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features).) Then I separate the data again (I had to merge so that I can generate dummies on the whole data space).

From here, I just run the svm stuff to fit the `x` and `y` labels and then to predict on `test_x`. I also had to encode/label `y`, from the string version to the numerical version. But yeah, it always produced `N` which I feel like is wrong. How do I fix? Thank you!

Comment: Try some other classifiers like LinearSVC() or KNeighborsClassifer() and check if they all produce same answers. If yes, then you may need to check your data .

Comment: Did you use the dataset as it is or did you modify before importing it?

Comment: I modified the dataset so that each DNA spot is its own variable and so I should have 60 feature variables and 1 output label.

Comment: I also used the Orange library to randomize the dataset and save to different files, which is why I had to combine them again at the start of the above script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is the way data is splitted into train and test. You have taken the first 3000 samples for training and the remaining 190 samples for testing. I found out that with such training the classifier yields the true class label for all the test samples (*score* = 1.0). I have also noticed that the last 190 samples of the dataset have the **same class label**, namely `'N'`. Therefore the result you obtained is correct.

I would recommend you to split the dataset into train and test through [`ShuffleSplit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html) with `test_size=.06` (this corresponds approximately to 190/3190 although to make visualization of results easier I used `test_size=.01` in the sample run below). For the sake of simplicity I would also suggest you to use [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to encode the categorical values of the features.

Here’s the full code (I have taken the liberty to perform some refactoring):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn import svm

data = np.loadtxt(r'splice.data', delimiter=',', dtype='string')

bases = {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'D': 2, 'G': 3, 'N': 4, 'R': 5, 'S': 6, 'T': 7}

X_base = np.asarray([[bases[c] for c in seq.strip()] for seq in data[:, 2]])
y_class = data[:, 0]

enc = OneHotEncoder(n_values=len(bases))
lb = LabelEncoder()

enc.fit(X_base)  
lb.fit(y_class)

X = enc.transform(X_base).toarray()
y = lb.transform(y_class)

rs = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=.01, random_state=0)
train_index, test_index = rs.split(X).next()
train_X, train_y = X[train_index], y[train_index]
test_X, test_y = X[test_index], y[test_index]

clf = svm.SVC(kernel="rbf")
clf.fit(train_X, train_y)

predictions = clf.predict(test_X)
```

Demo:

```
Out[2]: 
array(['IE', 'EI', 'EI', 'EI', 'EI', 'IE', 'N', 'N', 'EI', 'N', 'N', 'IE',
       'IE', 'N', 'N', 'IE', 'EI', 'N', 'N', 'EI', 'IE', 'EI', 'IE', 'N',
       'EI', 'N', 'IE', 'N', 'EI', 'N', 'N', 'EI'], 
      dtype='|S79')

In [3]: y_class[test_index]
Out[3]: 
array(['IE', 'EI', 'EI', 'EI', 'EI', 'IE', 'N', 'N', 'EI', 'N', 'N', 'IE',
       'IE', 'N', 'N', 'IE', 'EI', 'N', 'N', 'EI', 'IE', 'EI', 'IE', 'N',
       'IE', 'N', 'IE', 'N', 'EI', 'N', 'N', 'EI'], 
      dtype='|S79')

In [4]: clf.score(test_X, test_y)
Out[4]: 0.96875
```

*Note*: Make certain your sklearn version is 0.18.1, otherwise the code above might not work.

Comment: Nice! Please note that the code will only work with Python 2, with Python 3 it would be `data = numpy.loadtxt(r'splice.data', delimiter=',', dtype=bytes).astype(str)` and `train_index, test_index = rs.split(X).__next__()`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :) I will try this out

Comment: Can confirm works! I'm gonna look more at the docs to get better understanding. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tonechas @Maximilian Peters Why is it `n_values=[60]*X_base.shape[1]`? I thought `n_values` as an array means number of values per feature. Why not 8 for the number of bases that are possible? source: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. Good catch! I meant `n_values=[8]*60` but provided that all the 60 features can take 8 categorial values you should simply write `enc = OneHotEncoder(n_values=len(bases))`. I'm going to edit my answer to fix this bug.